# Crashlytics folder cannot find in 'Pods/Headers/Public' this path

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, crashlytics

When I run the project I got the error like ‘'Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h' file not found’.I am using Xcode10.1 with iOS12.

I installed  crashlytics  using the following lines in my pod file.

```
 pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7'

 pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.10.7'
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Did you use in swift project?

Comment: Did you open the project file or workspace file ?

Comment: I am using Objective-C and I opened workspace file

Comment: Do you receive the same error if you remove the version numbers and just put
`pod 'Fabric'`

`pod 'Crashlytics'`?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your project's **Framework Search Paths**

```
$(SRCROOT)/Pods/Crashlytics/iOS
```

[image]